# Discrete graphics and multiple users

Tags: nvidia, graphics, gpu, nvidia-optimus, 22.04

I have a 2014 Lenovo notebook with both integrated (Intel) and discrete (NVidia) graphics.

When I first boot the PC, and login, glxinfo shows the nvidia GPU.

After logout or user switch, the second user to log in gets the integrated GPU instead (noticeably slower, glxinfo shows the intel GPU)

Is this a problem I can solve through configuration, or is it just the way it is? I seem to remember that it worked on older versons (20.04, maybe 20.10).

The quick solution is to reboot the PC when a user needs the discrete GPU, but it still bothers me that it doesn't work as expected.

**Update:** I just upgraded today from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04, but it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind: This isn't specific to a single user, whoever logs in first gets the nvidia GPU, all other users have to go with intel.

Comment: Do you have nvidia-settings installed? `prime-select query` shows what is active, `sudo prime-select nvidia` switched to nVidia and `sudo prime-select intel` to integrated, No need  to reboot. If this works; you could add the command to startup.